# "No Activity found to handle Intent" error occurs when its going to load a URL in browser

Tags: android, android-intent, activitynotfoundexception

I've checked similar questions about `No Activity found to handle Intent` error. none of them covered my problem.

I'm getting this error in my Sentry logs when the app is going to open a URL in Chrome browser using Intent in an **AppCompatActivity**:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent
{ act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://www.example.com/...
flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.android.chrome }
```

This is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");

if (MyMethods.isAppInstalled(getApplicationContext(), "com.android.chrome")) {
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        SentryLog.warn(ex);
        // Chrome browser presumably not installed so allow user to choose instead
        intent.setPackage(null);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
} else {
    // Chrome browser presumably not installed so allow user to choose instead
    intent.setPackage(null);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

`SentryLog.warn(ex);` had reported the error.

and this is `isAppInstalled()` method which is in MyMethods class:

```
public static boolean isAppInstalled(Context context, String packageName) {
    try {
        if (context != null) {
            context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        }
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        MyLog.w(TAG, new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber(), e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

sometimes it goes to catch scope. As you see I checked if chrome is installed on device or not, so it's installed if it doesn't go to else! in this situation why it couldn't execute `startActivity(intent);` and it went to catch scope?

‍
My code is in an Activity, so should I use `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` or not?

Answer (score 0):

No need to check chrome it will find browser itself. 
Notice url must begin with http or https.

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
fragmentActivity.startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: I need to prioritize chrome for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
   try {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // chrome is not installed in the device
    }
```

you can do like this way to avoid the crash and also get that app installed or not.

Comment: @AlirezaNoorali this is worked for me in each case. so, you can try with this.

Answer (score 0):

To check if chrome is installed you can use below method

```
private boolean isChromeInstalled() {
    PackageInfo pInfo;
    try {
        pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.android.chrome", 0);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        //chrome is not installed on the device
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES` returns `1` you mean I should put `0` instead of `1`?

Comment: of course mu question is about `No Activity found to handle Intent` error.

Comment: first check if chrome is installed or not then start activity. this is alternative to the code you are using,.

Comment: try using `0` instead of `PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES`

Comment: Ok, Karan can you explain what's the difference between them?

Comment: you can check what each flag does from here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: I'll test it. Do you have any idea about my main problem, too? I mean the error.

Comment: your flag was checking for particular activity that can handle your intent, but there would be no activity like name you have passed. so the error

Comment: Which flag are you talking about? `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` ?

Comment: `PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES` checks for particular activity name that you provided in package name

Comment: No, I'm sure the main problem is not this flag. Ok, I'll change it but pay attention `SentryLog.warn(ex);` is executed because I got the exception in my sentry panel.